# Changing an OpenCV function Standard Parameters

Tags: c++, opencv

Is there a way to permanently change the standard parameters in a OpenCV function?
For example, how can I modify the MSER Feature Detector so that I can call

> MserFeatureDetector detector

instead of

> MserFeatureDetector detector(10,50,1000)

I am not precisley well versed in the inner mechanisms of C++ libraries, but I imagine the actual program code has to be somewhere, right?

A bit of information on my actual problem:

I'm currently using MEXOpenCV to run OpenCV functions in MatLab, and some MEX-Functions lack (as far as I know) the option to pass input parameters and run with the defaults like this:

```
  detector = cv.FeatureDetector('MSER'); % 'MSER' is the only parameter taken
```

I recon changing the standard parameters directly at the OpenCV programs would be a way to do it.

Any other ideas on how to solve the actual problem are welcome too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the actual problem by setting the parameters with the 'set' method of DescriptorExtractor like this 
     `detector=cv.FeatureDetector('MSER'); detector.set('delta',10);`